# Laptop keyboard not working

Tags: keyboard

My HP pavilion laptop keyboard don't work. However, I'm able to use a USB keyboard. The onscreen touchscreen keyboard works too.

I tried to change the setting in universal access, soft keys, and those items, but no change. I'm not sure what my next steps are?

Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: Does the keyboard work with Windows? With Ubuntu 18.04? With another linux distribution? If not, then probably a hardware issue.

Comment: Crud, I didn't think of that.  No, it doesn't work on windows either. I dual boot and it does not work in Grub either.  I guess it's the ribbon then.

Comment: Hardware problem, then. If that is the case, then you may want to delete the question: it is then unlikely to be useful for future readers.

Comment: I disagree, If I had seen this solution, I would not have posted the question, so I'd leave it for others to read, however, I thank you all for your help!

Comment: This is not a support forum, but rather an archive of questions and answers. So while this indeed helped you to identify the issue, the question as such will not be of much use for future users because it concerns defect hardware. Especially as now, the question does not include the information that it does not work elsewhere as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can test without having to find your installation LiveUSB (although it's certainly a valid method).

Please shut your system down, then reboot and [access the BIOS/firmware Setup](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c00034791).

1. If your Pavilion laptop was made after mid-2011, power on, and then
   repeatedly press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key until the Startup Menu
   opens. Press <kbd>F10</kbd> to enter the BIOS Setup Utility.
2. 2008-mid 2011? Some models might support pressing <kbd>F10</kbd> immediately after
   powering on the notebook to enter the Startup Menu.
3. Before 2008? Press <kbd>F10</kbd> to enter the BIOS just before the BIOS menu opens.

Navigate to the System Configuration screen, change something, then back out with <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

It works? Then it's a software issue. Doesn't work? Your keyboard internal ribbon cable has probably slipped out of contact. To go further, we'd need the model number from the serial number sticker. Other 'model' numbers elsewhere on your Pavilion are marketing names, and not the true model number required to find your Hardware manual.

Comment: In my case, I dual booted into windows and it didn't work there (nor in GRUB).  So, was a hardware issue.  Took it apart and the ribbon was seated, but removed it and replaced and now it works.

Comment: AOK! Suggest you check the check mark to the left of the top of my answer as well as the up arrowhead, to show it was a useful answer, plus it was the right answer.